# Powershell Transfer files under multiple subfolders to another folder under same Document Library Sharepoint

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have a document library "Documents1" which has multiple folders (aa, bb,cc, dd, Redundant).

Trying to write a powershell script to move files placed in multiple sub folders to folder  "redundant" under the same doc lib.

The files to be moved needs to be read from a .txt file which contains list of files names present under various sub folders.

```
 $WebURL="test.com"
 $SourceLibrary ="/Documents1"
 $TargetLibrary = "/Documents1/Redundant"
 $filenames = Get-Content 'F:\users\filelist.txt' 

#Get Objects $Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
 $SourceFile = $Web.GetFile($SourceLibrary) 
$Targetfile = $Web.GetFolder($TargetLibrary)
 foreach ($file in $filenames) { 
Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFile -Recurse | Where-Object -FilterScript {($_.name -match $file)} | Move-Item -Destination $Targetfile 
Write-Output "File moved " $file 
}
```

Comment: $file_list = Get-Content 'F:\users\filelist.txt' 
$web=Get-SPWeb "https://test.com"
$listName="Documents1"
$list = $web.Lists[$listName]
$search_folder = "Documents1"
$destination_folder = $Web.Url + "/" + $list.RootFolder.Url + "/"+ "Redundant"
foreach ($file in $file_list) {
 $file_to_move = Get-ChildItem -Path $search_folder -Recurse | Where-Object -FilterScript {($_.name -match $file)}
    if ($file_to_move) {Move-Item $file_to_move $destination_folder}}

Comment: the $_.name is showing a blank value and no idea why